# How to block a request for only rendered file javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller that creates a token using username password.

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public class TokenController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult GetToken()
    {
        // get token from another site using username and password.

        return Json(new{token}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

I am creating this token to use my other view pages. **cshtml** pages including javascript code this code calls **Token/GetToken** action method.

My Home controller is like this.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And my Home Index View is like

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Token/Get',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I run this code, the following error is occured. **500 (Internal Server Error)**

**The action 'Get' is accessible only by a child request.**

But Somebody that called this action method from browser, he can produce token.
http://domain.com/Token/GetToken like this. And somebody called my action via WebClient can produce token.

I do not want to these cases. Only my rendered file javascript codes should use my Token controller.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

use only `POST` method for preventing the browser url GET Request.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetToken()
{
}
```

in jQuery

```
 $.post('/Token/GetToken/',{}, function(){});
```

**OR** as per your updated post

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Token/Get',
        method:'post', //ADD THIS LINE
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

**Option 2:**

using [`ChildActionOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). This will ensure that url cannot be called directly like by browser or like REST. But it has to be accessed like `@Html.Action/RenderAction` you call this way and assign the Json result to some javascript variable with the help of `@Html.Raw`

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult GetToken()
{
}
```

In View

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var claim='@Html.Raw(Html.Action("GetToken", "Token"))';
   </script>
```

Comment: @bookmarker, please clearly read my answer. I gave you two option.. either use `POST` without childactiononly or go for the second option..